# How to generate a dynamic SVG path where point coordinates are fixed to an HTML element and item follows the path?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, svg-animate

My goal is to create something like this:

[Sketch of the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlAoB.png)

The yellow boxes represent divs whose number is dynamic. I need to generate a bezier curve whose loops are fixed below the image (red) since the position can change depending on the screen width. In addition, an element (black) follows the path once it reaches 50vh.

I found an npm package called svg-path-generator I could use to generate the path, but I don't know how to tackle this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-generator

This could be a way to let the element follow the path: https://animejs.com/documentation/#motionPath

How could I approach this?

This is the HTML I have so far with a working code pen: https://codepen.io/marcoluzi/pen/ZEjBBVo

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 128px;
}
.block__line-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.block__line-wrapper svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.block-item {
  display: grid;
  gap: 32px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .block-item {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .block-item {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 2fr 4fr 1fr;
  }
}
.block-item:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 96px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .block-item:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 144px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .block-item:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 192px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .block-item:nth-child(odd) .block-item__image-wrapper {
    grid-column: 2/4;
  }
  .block-item:nth-child(odd) .block-item__content {
    grid-column: 4/-1;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .block-item:nth-child(even) .block-item__image-wrapper {
    order: 2;
  }
  .block-item:nth-child(even) .block-item__content {
    order: 1;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .block-item:nth-child(even) .block-item__image-wrapper {
    grid-column: 3/-2;
  }
  .block-item:nth-child(even) .block-item__content {
    grid-column: 1/3;
  }
}
.block-item__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.block-item__content > * {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .block-item__content > * {
    max-width: 416px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-item">
    <figure class="block-item__image-wrapper has-image">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/639x354" width="641" height="354" />
      </picture>
    </figure>
    <div class="block-item__content">
      <h2 class="block-item__title">Title 1</h2>
      <p class="block-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-item">
    <figure class="block-item__image-wrapper has-image">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/639x354" class="block-item__image" width="641" height="354" />
      </picture>
    </figure>
    <div class="block-item__content">
      <h2 class="block-item__title">Title 2</h2>
      <p class="block-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-item">
    <figure class="block-item__image-wrapper has-image">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/639x354" class="block-item__image" width="641" height="354" />
      </picture>
    </figure>
    <div class="block-item__content">
      <h2 class="block-item__title">Title 3</h2>
      <p class="block-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__line-wrapper">
    <svg>
      <path/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't know how to answer this, but I may be able to contribute - https://bleeptrack.de this website does something similar to what you want to do I think, with each point the line goes to being where you clicked instead of where the next div is. She just does some fanciness and loopings along the way, and more lines.
She does this by creating an svg of the line using paper.js and then animating it using css. Hope that helps you somehow and you figure something out, would also be interested in the solution.

Comment: You can leave out the part about animation and motionpath. It should be dynamic in the sense that it should be responsive to the screen size. Can you add the code that you already have? It will help answer the question.

Comment: Here is the code I have so far @chrwahl
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/marcoluzi/pen/ZEjBBVo)
It's a Gutenberg Block created for WordPress. You can add as many .block-item Elements as you want. Thus I need to dynamically generate the line based on how many items there are and fix this curve to the block items. As you can see in the CodePen, my initial idea was to absolutely position an SVG inside the parent .block element and then generate the path.

Comment: Not what I was looking for. But cool effekt. :)

Comment: Well, add the link to your question then, or even better add the code as a snippet to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. First, I split up the SVGs as @chrwahl did in his answer. In addition, I used a tool I found called [leader-line](https://github.com/anseki/leader-line) to dynamically generate the SVGs. With this tool, you can pin the start and end point of a path to an HTML element, and it also offers a lot of customisation. In addition, I wrote a script that generates a circle for each path and fixes its position to that path.

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/marcoluzi/pen/XWBMzMY

```js
// generating the svg paths
document.querySelectorAll('.block').forEach(block => {
    const startElement = block.querySelector('.block__start');
    const items = block.querySelectorAll('.block-item');

    const options = {
        color: '#ef7852',
        dash: true,
        endPlug: 'behind',
    };

    const startLeaderLine = new LeaderLine(
        startElement,
        items[0].querySelector('.line-anchor'),
        {
            ...options,
            startSocket: 'left',
            endSocket: 'top',
            startSocketGravity: window.innerWidth > 768 ? [-200, 100] : [-100, 0],
            endSocketGravity: window.innerWidth > 768 ? [0, -300] : [0, -100],
        },
    );

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        startLeaderLine.setOptions({
            startSocketGravity: window.innerWidth > 768 ? [-200, 100] : [-100, 0],
            endSocketGravity: window.innerWidth > 768 ? [0, -300] : [0, -100],
        });
        startLeaderLine.position();
    });

    items.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (index < items.length - 1) {
            new LeaderLine(
                item.querySelector('.line-anchor'),
                items[index + 1].querySelector('.line-anchor'),
                {
                    ...options,
                    startSocket: 'bottom',
                    endSocket: 'top',
                    startSocketGravity: [0, 400],
                    endSocketGravity: [0, -400],
                },
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just to get your creative juices flowing you can position elements without complex coding

```html
<script>
customElements.define("svg-path-elements",class extends HTMLElement{
    connectedCallback(){
    let id = "curve" + this.getAttribute("id");
    let speed = 1; // set to 0.0001 for "instant" display
    let position = 0; // position of first element
    let elements = Array(~~this.getAttribute("count")||5).fill(0).map((_,idx,arr)=>{
      let inlineFunctionOnEnd = `this.closest('svg').parentNode.onend(${idx})`;
        let circle = `<circle id="circle${idx}" cx="0" cy="0" r="20" fill="green">
                      <animateMotion dur="${speed}s" keyPoints="0;${position}" 
                                     onend="${inlineFunctionOnEnd}"
                                     fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
                        <mpath href="#${id}"></mpath>
                      </animateMotion>
                    </circle>`
     position += 1/(arr.length-1);
     return circle;
    }).join("");
    this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="-50 50 1300 200" style="background:pink">
                      <path id="${id}" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5"
                            d="M 0 150 
                                q 150 -150 300 0
                                q 150 150 300 0
                                q 150 -150 300 0
                                q 150 150 300 0"></path>${elements}</svg>`;
  }
  onend(idx){
    let circle = this.querySelector("#circle"+idx);
    //console.log("positioned", this.id, circle.id );
  }
})</script>
<svg-path-elements id="FIVE" count="5"></svg-path-elements>
<svg-path-elements id="TEN" count="10"></svg-path-elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you split up the path in different SVG images and use these images as background for your HTML elements.

In the first snippet you can see alle the SVG images that I use, and in the second these SVG mages as backgrounds in a simplified version of your code (the dot does not behave when scaling up and down the page, but I don't have time to fix it -- maybe later).

I have set [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) for the SVG and [vector-effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect) for the paths. This combination ensures that the background image can be stretched if needed.

```css
svg {
  border: thin solid gray;
}
```

```html
<p>From top to left:</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 54 3 Q 54 5 50 5 Q 27 5 25 10" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
</svg>
<p>and the starting dot:</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="xMinyMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="54" cy="3" r="2" fill="black" />
</svg>
<p>From left to rigth:</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 25 0 Q 27 5 50 5 Q 73 5 75 10" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
</svg>
<p>From right to left:</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 75 0 Q 73 5 50 5 Q 27 5 25 10" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
</svg>
```

```css
div.block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

div.box {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 5em;
}

div.top {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwIiBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSJub25lIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0gNTQgMyBRIDU0IDUgNTAgNSBRIDI3IDUgMjUgMTAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iYmxhY2siIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iNCIgdmVjdG9yLWVmZmVjdD0ibm9uLXNjYWxpbmctc3Ryb2tlIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4K'), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwIiBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSJ4TWlueU1pZCBtZWV0IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgogIDxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjU0IiBjeT0iMyIgcj0iMiIgZmlsbD0iYmxhY2siIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50px,100% 50px;
}

div.left {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwIiBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSJub25lIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0gMjUgMCBRIDI3IDUgNTAgNSBRIDczIDUgNzUgMTAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iYmxhY2siIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iNCIgdmVjdG9yLWVmZmVjdD0ibm9uLXNjYWxpbmctc3Ryb2tlIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4K');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50px;
}

div.left div.box {
  order: 2;
}
div.left div.text {
  order: 1;
}

div.right {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwIiBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSJub25lIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0gNzUgMCBRIDczIDUgNTAgNSBRIDI3IDUgMjUgMTAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iYmxhY2siIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iNCIgdmVjdG9yLWVmZmVjdD0ibm9uLXNjYWxpbmctc3Ryb2tlIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top block">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="text">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="left block">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="text">Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test</div>
</div>
<div class="right block">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="text">Test</div>
</div>
```